# Java both If and else statements are executed

Tags: java

I wrote a little console app in java, which is made of If and else statements.
And on the output, both of the right If and else statements are executed.
How is it possible to fix? what's the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a first number");
    int FirstNum = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter an Operator");
    String Operator = in.next();

    System.out.println("Enter a second number");
    int SecondNum = in.nextInt();

    try{
        if(Operator.equals("+")){
            System.out.println(FirstNum + SecondNum);
        }
        if (Operator.equals("-")){
            System.out.println(FirstNum - SecondNum);
        }
        if (Operator.equals("*")){
            System.out.println(FirstNum * SecondNum);
        }
        if (Operator.equals("/")) {
            System.out.println(FirstNum / SecondNum);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("invalid Operator");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid Operator or number");
    }
}
```

}

Output example:

```
Enter a first number
1
Enter an Operator
+
Enter a second number
2
3
invalid Operator

Process finished with exit code 0
```

*JDK: java 15*

Comment: Java naming conventions use capital letters to start class names; methods, arguments, and variables start with lower case letters (secondNum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing if statements like this, you need to chain them together with `else if`, basically an `else` for every `if` with a final `else`. What is happening is you are saying "if this. And if this. And if this" etc. It is testing the last `if` and since it is not a forward slash, you are getting into the else.

Try this:

```
    if(Operator.equals("+")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum + SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum - SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("*")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum * SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("/")) {
        System.out.println(FirstNum / SecondNum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("invalid Operator");
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, and all who answered. I am new to Java, and I haven't had any problems like this before

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Is not possible execute both statements.

So, ¿what's happen? The structure if/else is only the last two lines. That is: If the operator is not `/` the code will execute the `else`statement.

You need an if/else if/else statement

```
if(Operator.equals("+")){
    System.out.println(FirstNum + SecondNum);
}
else if (Operator.equals("-")){
    System.out.println(FirstNum - SecondNum);
}
else if (Operator.equals("*")){
    System.out.println(FirstNum * SecondNum);
}
else if (Operator.equals("/")) {
    System.out.println(FirstNum / SecondNum);
}
else {
    System.out.println("invalid Operator");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `else if` for the subsequent statements. If you just use `if ... if ... if ... else`, then essentially each `if` is evaluated separately and only the FINAL `if else` is put together as one or the other.

```
try{
    if(Operator.equals("+")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum + SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum - SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("*")){
        System.out.println(FirstNum * SecondNum);
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("/")) {
        System.out.println(FirstNum / SecondNum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("invalid Operator");
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Invalid Operator or number");
}
```